# Sockets: ability to listen and send at the same time

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem:

My server needs to be able to do the following two functions:

- When an interrupt is received, the server needs to be able to send (multicast) to all clients the new XYZ information
- When a new client joins the broadcast group, it needs said XYZ information. The server will need to be able to process a read request from the client for XYZ.

So the server needs to be capable of listening for requests from clients, while at the same time sending information to clients on the interrupt event.

My client  needs to be able to do the following two functions:

- When it first joins the broadcast group, it needs to be able to read XYZ from the server.
- When the server experiences an interrupt event it will send out XYZ. My client needs to be listening for that information.

I expect the client to only need to request for XYZ on the initial join. After that it should only be listening for XYZ from the server.

Is this possible? I have looked into blocking/non-blocking and related methods.

Comment: Look into `select()` and `poll()`.

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes.  It really depends on how you design the dialog between the client and server.  For example, the server needs to listen and respond to requests, like "data=?" with "data=XYZ" or however you want to package the message.

The server needs to broadcast when it starts-up, and the clients need to go into a listen mode when connection with server is lost.

To implement this, you will probably use threads on both the client and server and therefore probably some amount of serialization (semaphores, mutexs, etc).  Specifically, you will probably end-up with one thread with a listen socket and another thread with a send socket.

Overall, this is a medium skill project, but unless you have previously coded a multi-threaded application or a TCP/IP application then it will be a learning experience!

PS.  I am doing something similar, just for fun, so it is possible!

Comment: serialization? I believe you mean synchronization.

Comment: @zoska, the computer science terminology is serialization.  Synchronization implies that two events are made to happen as co-ordinated events while serialization says that events are made to occur one after another, but the time delay between them is **NOT** controlled or synchronized.

Comment: Oh, damn, I see. You are right. Though I have never heard term serializations in this context.